# Create an Annotation in Dart lang

Tags: flutter, dart

I want create an **annotation** in class property.
Example:

```
class Annotation {
        const Annotation(this.prop)
        final String prop;
    }

class Model{
    @Annotation("int_prop")
    Int prop;
}
```

I tried use **reflection** but I not found the **metadata**, some one with an idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I write an annotation for Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456451/how-can-i-write-an-annotation-for-dart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem understanding better the dart-lang reflection. Basically with reflection you have a reference of Object contains the metadata and value of variables and methods of Class.
This is my example to find the metadata of a class property.

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

void main(List<String> args) {
  Model model = Model(prop: "property value");

  InstanceMirror mirror = reflect(model);

  // this is Map<Symbol,DeclarationMirror> contains properties (VariableMirrors) ,constructors and methods (MethodMirror) of
  // a Model mirror instance
  var mirrorDeclarations = mirror.type.declarations;

  mirrorDeclarations.forEach((symbol, member) {
    if (member is VariableMirror) {
      print("A List of Instance Mirror of Annotation ${member.metadata}");
      // result:A List of Instance Mirror of Annotation [InstanceMirror on Instance of 'Annotation']

      //find a specific metadata
      InstanceMirror annotation = member.metadata.firstWhere(
          (mirror) => mirror.type.simpleName == #Annotation,
          orElse: () => null);
      print("the Instance Mirror of Annotation ${annotation}");
      //result: the Instance Mirror of Annotation InstanceMirror on Instance of 'Annotation'

      //get reflectee, property value, using a Symbol
      print(
          "Annotation param value = ${annotation.getField(#param).reflectee}");
    }
    //result: Annotation param value = value example
  });
}

// simple annotation class
class Annotation {
  const Annotation({this.param});
  final String param;
}

//class property using annotation
class Model {
  Model({this.prop = ""});

  @Annotation(param: "value example")
  final String prop;
}
```